# How to find the relation between a USB/TTL (dev/ttyUSB_) and it's GPIO pins (/dev/gpiochip_)

Tags: serial-port, gpio

I have a number of USB/TTL adapters, based on CP2102N, which have four GPIO lines.

I can open one of the serial devices by `/dev/ttyUSB0`, and the related GPIO lines are controlled by `libgpiod`: `/dev/gpiochip1`.

I need to make sure I am always modifying the right device and I need a way to figure out the relation either by querying `/dev/ttyUSB0` resulting in -> `/dev/gpiochip1`, or by querying `/dev/gpiochip1` resulting in -> `/dev/ttyUSB0`.

How do I do that? I don't see anything in `libgpiod` that does this.

Comment: Assuming linux, in the kernel source there is a directory `tools/gpio`. Building them and running `lsgpio` may give you a bit more info.

Answer (score 0):

You could try `readlink /sys/class/gpio/gpiochip1` and/or `readlink /sys/class/tty/ttyUSB0`, and seeing if the two paths have the same controller and USB device components.

For example, if you get something like:

```
# readlink /sys/class/gpio/gpiochip1
../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-7/1-7:1.0/gpio/gpiochip1
# readlink /sys/class/tty/ttyUSB0
../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-7/1-7:1.0/ttyUSB0/tty/ttyUSB0
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
The same PCI USB controller and USB device path!
```

then you'd know that ttyUSB0 == gpiochip1.

Comment: Thanks, worked good.